# How do I change the Integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I found this other thread:
[Calculation of Complex Integral using residue theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544201/calculation-of-complex-integral-using-residue-theorem)

Now I wonder, how I can get from the Integral over $[0,2 \pi]$ to the circle Integral over Gamma.

I understood, that they replaced the $\sin t$ with eulers formula to $1/2i \times (z-1/z)$, but still I miss the point how they end up with the next line.

Comment: It's $\sin t=\dfrac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$, then substitute $z=e^{it}$ and $dz=ie^{it}\,dt$.